# Sparsematrix for mapply

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, mapply

I am attempting to use mapply because I have used forloop but it takes a very long time to run so I'm attempting to use mapply to compute a large sparsematrix dataset in r  but I ran into this error

```
Error in (function (t)  : 
  unused arguments (dots[[2]][[1]], dots[[3]][[1]])
```

This is a smaller dataset

```
fam <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 5L, 7L), dad = c(0L, 
                                                                  0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 5L), mum = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 6L), 
                      GEN = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                -7L))
```

```
library(Matrix)
hom = function(fam) {
  t1 <- min(which.max(fam$dad > 0), which.max(fam$mum > 0))
  t2 <- max(fam[["ID"]])
  A<-Matrix(0, nrow=t2,ncol=t2, sparse=TRUE)
  diag(A) <- 2-0.5^(fam[["GEN"]]-1)
 A<-mapply(t=t1:t2, function(t) A[[t,t]]<- sum(2-0.5^(fam[[t,"GEN"]]-  1)+0.5^(fam[t,"GEN"])*A[fam[t,"dad"],fam[t,"mum"]]),
    mapply(j=1:length(t-1), function(j)
      A[t,j]<-0.5*sum(c(A[j,fam[t,"dad"]],A[j,fam[t,"mum"]]))
    ), A <- as.numeric(tril(A)+t(tril(A, -1))))
return(A)
}
```

What could be causing the error and how can I correct it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The function signature for mapply is

`mapply(FUN, ..., MoreArgs = NULL, SIMPLIFY = TRUE, USE.NAMES = TRUE)`

As a result, the first unnamed argument becomes `FUN` (in your case , `function(t)...`). Your named t argument (`t = t=t_start:t_end`) get passed to this. All the other unnamed arguments also get passed to `FUN`. In your code, `mapply` is also passing

`mapply(j=1:length(t-1), function(j) A[t,j]<-0.5*sum(c(A[j,fam[t,"dad"]],A[j,fam[t,"mum"]])))`

and

`A <- as.numeric(tril(A)+t(tril(A, -1))`

as arguments as well to the `function(t)`, i.e. it is passing three arguments to a lambda function that expects only 1 argument (`t`). As a result an error is thrown. It would be similar to calling:

```
myTriple <- function(x) 3*x
myTriple(1, 2, 3)
```

I'm not sure what your intent is with the other lines after the first `mapply` call so to fix it you either need to make `function(t)` take (and use) the additional arguments, move them into the `function(t)` definition, or move them out of the call. Here is your `mapply` call formatted to make it a little more obvious what's going on. All the arguments to `mapply` have the same indentation:

```
  A <- mapply(t=t_start:t_end, 
            function(t) A[[t,t]]<- sum(2-0.5^(fam[[t,"GEN"]]-  1) + 0.5^(fam[t,"GEN"])*A[fam[t,"dad"],
                                       fam[t,"mum"]]
            ),
            mapply(j=1:length(t-1), 
                   function(j) A[t,j]<-0.5*sum(c(A[j,fam[t,"dad"]],A[j,fam[t,"mum"]]))), 
            A <- as.numeric(tril(A)+t(tril(A, -1)))
  )
```

Comment: thanks, how can i make ```function (t)``` use the other arguments bearing in mind that ```function (j)``` has the ```j=1:lenght(t-1)``` call?

Comment: The trivial answer is make it `function(t, x, y)` but I don't think that solves what you're actually trying to do. I'm not sure `mapply` is the function you're looking for. Perhaps you realize this but the 'm' is for the multiple arguments you pass to a function, not matrix. I don't completely follow what you're trying to accomplish, but the way you have it formulated it seems like you are still defining each element individually which won't be any more efficient than the for loops. Efficiency would come if you can reformulate it to vectorize the definition of whole rows or columns